# Mobile safari : frame.src vs window.location

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, webkit

**Hi,** quick question.

What is the best way to call native from webview. An **iframe** or a **window.location** ?

eg:

```
gapBridge = document.createElement("iframe");
gapBridge.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
gapBridge.setAttribute("height","0px");
gapBridge.setAttribute("width","0px");
gapBridge.setAttribute("frameborder","0");
document.documentElement.appendChild(gapBridge);
gapBridge.src = custom + "://" + custom;
```

or :

```
window.location = custom + "://" + custom;
```

Ps : btw changing the src in embeded webview does not seem to work. As revealed by other article on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447607/mobile-safari-and-iframe-src-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iframe seems to be better on my case. The problem I see with `window.location` is that if you have multiple calls in sequence the browser will ignore some. While using an iframe you can actually create multiple iframes one for each call. I also delete the iframe after a delay so I don't find myself with a huge DOM of empty iframes.

Here's the function I use:

```
function _callNative(url){
    var _frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    _frame.width=0; _frame.height=0;_frame.frameBorder=0;
    document.body.appendChild(_frame);
    if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0){
        url = url + "&cb=";
    }else{
        url = url + "?cb=";
    }
    _frame.src = url + Math.round(Math.random()*1e16);
    // Remove the iframe
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.removeChild(_frame);}, 2000);
}
```

eg:

```
_callNative('native://doSomethingNative()');
_callNative('native://doSomethingElse')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :)
When i said iframe i refered to a single instance of this iframe. I see you used many of them. Do you have any info on why this is better ?
Also you said "_The problem I see with window.location is that if you have multiple calls in sequence the browser will ignore some._" do you have a link ? :)
Thanks !

Comment: This is all based on my own experience, sorry I don't have a link. The best thing is to try it yourself, try with one iframe, with window.location and with multiple iframes. All methods should work fine, but I needed to perform several calls in sequence and it was just registering one. The method with multiple iframes is the only one that did the trick for me. You should try yourself and see.

Comment: I don't believe this if I don't see it. This testbed is performing 8000 successful calls back and forth using various methods (including window.locaion) https://github.com/mihaip/web-experiments/tree/master/webview-communication . Would like to see proof of this. Really don't like to overengineer.

Comment: This post is over 3 years old. I don't think the method is that complicated I wouldn't call it over engineering. I haven't done much iOS dev these last years so I can't say if the limitation I saw 3 years ago still stand. I myself like to err on safe side. I find opening these URLs on iframes also more elegant. But do your own research I'm not here to prove anything to you and do whatever you think is best.

Comment: Sorry if I came out a little hard there. You are right btw. This guy http://blog.persistent.info/2013/10/a-faster-uiwebview-communication.html can confirm that repeatedly setting location.href in the same spin of the event loop results in only the final navigation happening. Using iframes is one way to circumvent this.

Comment: You may btw delete the iframe immediately since the call is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rundown of different alternatives with performance considered: 
http://blog.persistent.info/2013/10/a-faster-uiwebview-communication.html
http://blog.persistent.info/2015/08/wkwebview-communication-latency.html

Basically if you are supporting iOS 8 or below then you might be best off with `location.replace`.

If you are supporting iOS 9 and above and the difference is minimal and you can choose wether you prefer `location.replace` or `WKScriptMessageHandler`.