# How do I open an URL in iOS using iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function () { 
        var url = $('#url').val();
        $("#frame").attr("src", url);
    });
});
```

I am trying using the above and it is working fine with Android but URL doesn't open on iOS. Can someone please suggest on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this topic: [Mobile Safari and iFrame src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447607/mobile-safari-and-iframe-src-attribute?rq=1)
you can try to create new iFrame instead of changing src property of the old one.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = '';
    $("#button").click(function () {
        if (id) $('#' + id).remove(); //remove the old iframe
        var url = $('#url').val();
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        var dt = new Date();
        id = "ifr" + dt.getTime();
        iframe.id = id;
        iframe.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    });
});
```